# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 while running swift module

Tags: swift, react-native, bridge, native-module

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OMIDAdEvents", referenced from:

info       objc-class-ref in libRNReactNativeOmSdk.a(RNReactNativeOmSdk-2c77bc9bed4a883b1045973f1be92117cfac9436c99e071bcb8044045048f9c5.o)

info   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OMAdSession", referenced from:

info       objc-class-ref in libRNReactNativeOmSdk.a(RNReactNativeOmSdk-2c77bc9bed4a883b1045973f1be92117cfac9436c99e071bcb8044045048f9c5.o)

info   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OMConfiguration", referenced from:

info       objc-class-ref in libRNReactNativeOmSdk.a(RNReactNativeOmSdk-2c77bc9bed4a883b1045973f1be92117cfac9436c99e071bcb8044045048f9c5.o)

info   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OMContext", referenced from:

info       objc-class-ref in libRNReactNativeOmSdk.a(RNReactNativeOmSdk-2c77bc9bed4a883b1045973f1be92117cfac9436c99e071bcb8044045048f9c5.o)

info   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OMPartner", referenced from:

info       objc-class-ref in libRNReactNativeOmSdk.a(RNReactNativeOmSdk-2c77bc9bed4a883b1045973f1be92117cfac9436c99e071bcb8044045048f9c5.o)
```

Can any one tell me why this is happening, I have created a module in swift and using it as npm package in other project.but when I run my project I am facing this issue.Please help me to solve this problem.any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you set imports in build phases. Delete derived data, clean, build again.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban follow the same steps, still getting same error